# CSV column has list of lists. How do I turn this column into a relational database with sqlite?

Tags: python, json, pandas, sqlite, csv

I am new to all this and just can't seem to find a way to make this work. So I have a JSON that I used python to convert to a CSV. I am having 2 issues.

The first one you might be able to help me understand conceptually. When I use pandas to read the JSON file, I can correctly access my list of lists using slices, like so:

*Row 1 of this "fermentables" column looks like this:*

```
[[2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], [0.907, 'American - White Wheat', 40.0, 2.8, 17.0], [0.907, 'American - Pale 6-Row', 35.0, 1.8, 17.0], [0.227, 'Flaked Corn', 40.0, 0.5, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Caramel / Crystal 20L', 35.0, 20.0, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)', 33.0, 1.8, 4.3], [0.113, 'Flaked Barley', 32.0, 2.2, 2.1], [0.34, 'Honey', 42.0, 2.0, 6.4]]
```

`print(data['fermentables'][0])` gets me the exact same list -

```
[[2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], [0.907, 'American - White Wheat', 40.0, 2.8, 17.0], [0.907, 'American - Pale 6-Row', 35.0, 1.8, 17.0], [0.227, 'Flaked Corn', 40.0, 0.5, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Caramel / Crystal 20L', 35.0, 20.0, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)', 33.0, 1.8, 4.3], [0.113, 'Flaked Barley', 32.0, 2.2, 2.1], [0.34, 'Honey', 42.0, 2.0, 6.4]]
```

`print(data['fermentables'][0][0])` gets me the first list -

```
[2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7]
```

`print(data['fermentables'][0][0])` gets me [2.3810000000000002]

HOWEVER when I try to do the same thing using pandas to access the csv, I get:

```
print(data['fermentables'][0])) = [[2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], [0.907, 'American - White Wheat', 40.0, 2.8, 17.0], [0.907, 'American - Pale 6-Row', 35.0, 1.8, 17.0], [0.227, 'Flaked Corn', 40.0, 0.5, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Caramel / Crystal 20L', 35.0, 20.0, 4.3], [0.227, 'American - Carapils (Dextrine Malt)', 33.0, 1.8, 4.3], [0.113, 'Flaked Barley', 32.0, 2.2, 2.1], [0.34, 'Honey', 42.0, 2.0, 6.4]]

print((data['fermentables'][0][0]))= [
```

Why doesn't my list of lists act like a list from my CSV?

---

2nd question, and what I'm trying to accomplish:

I converted this to CSV so I could import it into a SQLite database. There are several more columns that have lists like the 'fermentables' and I would very much like to use that information, however I have no idea to make these SQLite friendly and turn them into a relational database (especially when I'm having the list access above).

As you can see, there are multiple lists, each with 5 elements. This is the entire "fermentable" recipe for 1 beer, where each element is 'weight', 'grain_name', 'ppg', 'deg_litner', 'grain_bill' (I want them labeled, they currently do not have labels, but this is what the data is in that order). I am trying to turn this into something that can I query, for example, the most used grain name in all the beer recipes. But as it is I can't do that. it's possible I'm just not experienced enough to know the terminology to ask google or stack overflow to find the right answer, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Basalty.  My first thought is to use a table like `CREATE TABLE(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, weight REAL, grain_name TEXT, ppg REAL, deg_litner REAL, grain_bill REAL)`.  One clarifying question - are there multiple list of lists?  e.g. is the data shaped like `[[[2.3810000000000002, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 44.7], ..., ], [[1.53, '1st Item In Second List of Lists', 32.0, 1.22, 43.7], ...], ...]`? If so, what is the difference between the first row and the second row? Does each row include all fermentables of a specific category?

Comment: Hi Max! Thanks for helping. Yes each row is different from the next, so they don't have the same amount of lists. Each row has several measurements for each type of grain used, so there can be one list or many. For example the next row only has 2 lists:
[[5.216, 'American - Pale 2-Row', 37.0, 1.8, 92.7], [0.41200000000000003, 'American - Caramel / Crystal 60L', 34.0, 60.0, 7.3]]

Comment: Solid. Can you clarify what causes them to be put in different rows. For example, is row one all Lagers and row two all Stouts, so on and so forth?

Comment: Each row is the fermentable recipe for a beer, like "vanilla porter" or "sierra nevada pale ale clone"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table that matches the "leaf nodes" in your list of lists. You could run something like this in the `sqlite` command line shell:

```
CREATE TABLE fermentable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, weight REAL, grain_name TEXT, ppg REAL, deg_litner REAL, grain_bill REAL);
```

And then insert your rows with a python script:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(<dbfilepath>,
    # turn off autocommit for better performance
    isolation_level=None
)
cur = con.cursor()
# turn off safety features to speed up the bulk insert
cur.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode=off;") 
cur.execute("PRAGMA synchronous=off;")
for fermentables in list_of_lists:
    for f in fermentables:
        con.execute("INSERT INTO fermentable VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", f)
cur.close()
con.close();
```

Since each lead value has the same five fields, you just need to access each one using a nested loop, then run a normal insert.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I haven't had a chance to try this yet but thanks so much for your help!! I really appreciate it.